# adding php array values to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a php array and I want to add its value to a javascript array. For example I am doing it something like this.

```
$k_data = json_encode($k)
```

Thus

> k_data = [2,3,4,8,9]

Now in javascript I am doing like the following

```
var s4 = [[]];
for(var i = 0; i<5; i++)
{ 
   s4.push([i,$k_data[i]]);
}
plot5.series[0].data = s4;
```

where plot5 is jqplot graph. But this is not working, I am getting blank graph while the following thing is working

```
for(var i = 0; i<5; i++)
{ 
   s4.push([i,Math.sin(i)]);
}
```

Where I am making mistake?

Comment: The code can either be complete js or complete PHP.

Comment: can anyone explain me why -2?

Comment: I am using yii framework so I need both js and php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deal with the php array only, you can do this-

First, **[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)** the array to make a comma-separated string, say `$str`. Just like-

```
<?php
  $str = implode(",", $array);
?>
```

Then, use **[split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)** to convert the php string to the javascript array. Just like-

```
<script>
  var str = <?php echo $str; ?>;
  var array = str.split(',');
</script>
```

---

OR, json_encode() can help you directly-

```
<script>
 <?php
  $js_array = json_encode($php_array);
  echo "var js_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
 ?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do a for loop and echo the Javascript commands to fill the Javascript Array

```
<script>
var s4 = [[]];

<?php

$k_data = json_encode($k)
$i = 0;

foreach($k_data as $v) { 
   echo 's4.push([' , $i , ',Math.sin(' , $v , ')]);';

   ++$i;
}

?>

plot5.series[0].data = s4;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are refering to a php variable in you javascript. Keep in mind that PHP is executed serverside, whereas javascript is executed by the browser. Therefore, you need to pass the PHP variable to your javascript. Assuming that your javascript and PHP are in one .php file, replacing above javascript with the following should work:

```
<?php $k_data_js = implode("','", $k_data); ?>
var k_data = <?php echo "['" . $k_data_js . "']"; ?>;
var s4 = [[]];
for(var i = 0; i<k_data.length; i++)
{ 
   s4.push([i,k_data[i]]);
}
plot5.series[0].data = s4;
```

The variable is passed to javascript in the second line. From then on you can refer to `k_data` in your script.